# LESS target every element of type unless it's within certain div

Tags: css, less

I'm looking for a neat way to solve the given problem:

Let's say we have an article, and I want to style every `h1`, `h2` in unless they are located in the `<div ="example">`

```
<article class="article">
  <h1>Direct Child 1</h1>
  <h2>Direct Child 2</h2>

  <div class="example">
    <h1>Example Child 1</h1>
    <h2>Example Child 2</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="other-div">
    <h1>Indirect Child 1</h1>
    <h2>Indirect Child 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in pure CSS the solution is simple:

```
.article > h1,
.article *:not(.example) h1 {
  color: red;
}

.article > h2,
.article *:not(.example) h2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

All `h1`s are red, and `h2`s are blue, unless they're within `<div class=example>"` - [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbPmeO)

In LESS, however, I can't find a **clean way** to do this.

```
.article {
  & :not(.example)  {
    h1 {
      color: red;
    }

    h2 {
      color:  blue;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to add `<div class=article>"` direct child `h1`s and `h2` into the mix while keeping it DRY.

Comment: The only DRY ways would be either of the two used [here](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.article%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%3E%20h1%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%3Anot(.example)%20h1%20%7B%20%26%3Aextend(.article%20%3E%20h1)%3B%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%3E%20h2%2C%20%3Anot(.example)%20h2%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%20blue%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

Comment: @Harry Yep, I'm leaning towards #2 too, but it gets ugly when you ave 7-8 types of elements to target :(

Comment: Yeah, I can understand where you're coming from but we need two *insert* operations here in the middle of the nesting - one for the `>` and the other for the `:not(.example)`. At the moment that doesn't seem possible. There is an open feature request to target and *insert* selectors in the middle of a chain and when that is implemented, this may become easier.

Comment: Aside of my answer below, I wonder if (depending on your actuall code not just the example) you should not make it up-side-down. I.e. instead of setting the styles that "are not something" (honestly things like `*:not(something)` are always weird and suspicious) one simply sets styles for a thing that is that something (e.g. `article > example h1` etc). E.g. somewhat [like this](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/NbPVeW?editors=1100#0).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Totally agree with you. This, however, is a style guide that includes live site's css to show example blocks from it within the article that has a different styling. So this seems like the only sane feasible option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the main show-stopper for your attempt is the limitation of Less requiring a selector combinator (like `>`) to always go before a selector element (so neither `& >` nor `>` alone can work). 
There's workaround however:

```
.article {
    @-: ~'>'; 
    @{-}, *:not(.example) {
        h1 {color: red}
        h2 {color: blue}
    }
}
```

Comment: And yes, as already mentioned in comments above: remember that being DRY is never actually the goal because the DRY itself is just a way to get it more maintainable *and* readable (*that* is the goal). So if an attempt to go DRY via nesting totally kills either of those one should leave plain CSS code (nothing wrong in having some selector element repeated if compared to zillion `{...}` and `&` blocks spread all over the whole screen in case of an unsuccessful nesting attempt making things just absolutely cryptic and nearly impossible to understand).

Comment: Hahaha, yes that's a valid option. Just that it gets complicated to read.

Comment: @seven-phases-max This is brilliant, thank you! Being DRY in this particular case would mean easier adding more elements into the nesting (h3, h4, h5, a, etc.) doesn't become a bloat of weird selector repeated over and over, instead, it's easier to explain the top two lines of code in a comment. Again, thank you, this is great.